# What's /system/vendor/lib/liboemcrypto.so?

Tags: lineageos, drm

and where does it come from? I'm on lineage os and I have an app that crashes because this file doesn't exist on my sytem. When I do an internet search for the file, I see that there are plenty of people getting things working by removing it, or renaming it to `liboemcrypto.so.bak` or something, but no one seems to be missing this file. Can I get it from anywhere?

Comment: What app is crashing?

Comment: The app's name is [magine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magine.aliceoid&hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's (part of the) implementation of Android's "modular DRM", which came into being in Android 4.3 (API level 18) -- see [MediaDrm](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm.html). Essentially it's the component that allows media player apps, under certain conditions, to play back DRM-protected contents.

If you are running on Android 4.2 or lower, however, you're probably out of luck. To confirm, you can install an app like [DRM Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidfung.drminfo&hl=en), which will tell you whether any DRM library is installed on your system. If not, am afraid there's nothing you can do on this specific device.

Comment: Sorry, I could have mentioned that I'm on lineageos. Any idea why this file might be missing. I've installed DRM Info, and it says that "Google Widevine Modular DRM" is supported, but "Microsoft Playready DRM", "Marlin DRM" and "Veramatrix VCAS" are not.

Comment: Not familiar with LineageOS per se, but my best guess is that -- since liboemcrypto must be implemented by the device's OEM (for robustness reasons, as it is tightly integrated with hardware security components such as TrustZone) -- a device reflashed with a 3rd-party OS will not be able to have that hardware integration and will therefore need to omit that library.